# Network interface change required for IPv6 enablement on systemd based linux system

Tags: networking, ipv6, systemd

I am trying to enable IPv6 support for my framework which uses systemd linux system. So,
Currently my network interface file(/etc/systemd/networkd/eth0.network) is something like this for DHCP enabled connection:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=0

and this as static IP setting:
[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
Address=x.x.x.x/n
```

Does this network interface require any change for supporting IPv6? I am following the resources available here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd but, unfortunately couldn't find much.
Can someone please help me with this or share any resources available for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages which can help you to configure ipv6 by example the net-tool package  has some tools like ifconfig and route which help you to configure IPv6 on an interface.

Look at the output of ifconfig -? or route -?, if something is shown like IPv6 or inet6, then the tool is IPv6-ready.

Auto-magically check:

```
# /sbin/ifconfig -? 2>& 1|grep -qw 'inet6' && echo "utility 'ifconfig' is
¬ IPv6-ready"
```

Same check can be done for route:

```
# /sbin/route -? 2>& 1|grep -qw 'inet6' && echo "utility 'route' is IPv6-ready"
```

If your current network was configured to use IPv4 and you are not suffering of ip address exhaustion you could  keep your IPV4 and DHCP   ,The IPV6 protocol was deployed to have more public ips and avoid the public ip exhaustion due the limit of IPV4  address available on the internet.

However if you are thinking start to migrate to IPv6 because is easier to configure and maintain than ipv4, and you don't want keep fighting with complicated subnetting rules, then make sense deploy a DHCPv6 in your LAN to start a smooth transition, So to start with this new deployment you can consult this [link](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3235384/ipv6-address-enterprises-how-to-easier-than-ipv4.html) to find more details about DHCP and DHCPv6

Comment: By any chance u can explain when to use [Network]
DHCP=ipv6 or ipv4   ..... DHCP = yes does the same thing right?

Comment: @shandilya, IPv6 DHCP is different than IPv4 DHCP, using multicast and automatically assigned link-local addresses, and it does not assign things like a default gateway that must come from the RAs. Also, the RAs actually allow or deny the host to use stateful or stateless configuration.